# React basic list using class components not working

Tags: reactjs

New to React and trying to follow this page: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

I have two components:

### App.js

```
var React = require('react');
var NumberList = require('./NumberList');

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>Hello {this.props.name} from React!</h1>
      <NumberList numbers={[1,2,3,4,5]} />
    </div>;
  }
}

module.exports = App;
```

### NumberList.js

```
var React = require('react');

class NumberList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const numbers = props.numbers;
    const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
      <li>{number}</li>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return <ul>test {listItems}</ul>;
  }
}

module.exports = NumberList;
```

### index.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var App =
require('./components/App');

ReactDOM.render(
  <App name="Sarah"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I am getting a Javascript error:

```
listItems not defined
```

Do I need to store listItems as a state somehow?

### Update

I tried changing:

```
return <ul>test {listItems}</ul>;
```

to

```
return <ul>test {this.listItems}</ul>;
```

I just get a blank "test" word and no list items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your constructor, if you write

```
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li>{number}</li>
);
```

then `listItems` is a local variable, the `render` function cannot aware of it.

if you want to access via `this.listItems` in `render`, you will need to write:

```
this.listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li>{number}</li>
);
```

but this may not work because when your component is being constructed, the props may not have been passed down yet. You will need to write this in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Usually you can just write the `.map` in the render function, and don't forget the `key`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.props.numbers.map((number, i) =>
        <li key={i}>{number}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

If you don't like this style, simply extract this to a function or in a variable, for example:

```
render() {
  const listItems = this.props.numbers.map((number, i) =>
    <li key={i}>{number}</li>
  )

  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  )
}
```